# Parse only the first variable $ _GET with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The URL of searcher is:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?category=search&customsearch=true&group=2&ref=&guests=1&rooms=1&city=6265&arrival=1363215600000&departure=1363474800000
```

But, i need translate de page to other languages, and agree the "lang" param in the url.

```
..://www.domain.com/index.php?category=search&customsearch=true&group=2&ref=&guests=1&rooms=1&city=6265&arrival=1363215600000&departure=1363474800000**&lang=it**
```

I wish i could call the url of this form:

```
..://www.domain.com/**it**/index.php?category=search&customsearch=true&group=2&ref=&guests=1&rooms=1&city=6265&arrival=1363215600000&departure=1363474800000
```

...and that the parameters are not lost.

Can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php?category=(.+)&customsearch=(.+)&group=(.+)&.......&lang=(.+)?$ http://www.domain.com/(LAST $ VALUE)/index.php?category=$1&customsearch=$2&group=$3&..........
```

similar like this, the last index number of lang will be place at (`LAST $ VALUE`)